# A quick exercise on the Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics

What is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(2x-5)^{24}(3-4x)^{60}$.

So applying the Binomial Theorem, we get

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{24}{24\choose k}(2x)^k(-5)^{24-k}\times\sum\limits_{n=o}^{60}{60\choose n}(-4x)^n3^{60-n}$; and I say the coefficient of $x^2$ is:

${24\choose 0}5^{24}{60\choose 2}(-4)^23^{58}+{24\choose 1}2(-5)^{23}{60\choose 1}(-4)3^{59}+{24\choose 2}2^25^{22}{60\choose 0}3^{60} $

But the answer I have been given is,

${24\choose 0}5^{24}{60\choose 3}(-4)^33^{57}+{24\choose 1}2(-5)^{23}{60\choose 2}(-4)2^{58}+{24\choose 2}2^25^{22}{60\choose 2}(-4)^23^{59} $

So which one is right, if any and if the 2nd is right please can you explain why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.  The other answer looks like somebody started to find the coefficient of $x^3$ and gave up along the way.